# Efficient creation of filtering rules in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

I have selected a received email in Mail.app and would like to create a rule to redirect all emails from the same sender to a specific folder. I know how to create such rules manually from the preferences menu. However, I wonder if there is any way to do this more efficiently by having some information from the selected email being filled in automatically? I checked the menus and in-app help, but couldn't find anything in this direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the email then using preferences->rules will fill in the values from theemail in the selections e.g. if you choose From it will show who the email is from.